# Weird spacing using ShareActionProvider and Split Actionbar in ABS

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

I'm using the compatibility ShareActionProvider in a Split Actionbar thanks to ActionbarSherlock - however, I'm getting weird spacing issues once the icon expands to fit in the "history" menu - the icon for the last/most used sharing option is pushing the other elements in my actionbar around and spacing them oddly. Does anyone know how I'd address/fix this? Would somehow disabling the history stop the "double" icon from showing up? Or is there some way I can just make it a normal icon that upon pressing brings up a "Choose an action" popup or something?

Here's an image for reference

https://i.stack.imgur.com/a2IwG.png